# jQuery sortable list but not allowing element to be dragged into another list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

Hi I want to use jQuery sortable for a client of mine to use to order banners on their sites rotator.

I have two lists sortable1 and sortable2, `sortable1` refers to banners already selected and two are banners to chose from.

By default the company requires two of the banners to default therefore cannot be removed from the div `sortable1` but these can be sorted.

To try and achieve this I changed the class of my li to `ui-state-disabled` but this only lead to it not been sortable which is not what I require.

Does any one know how I can achieve this not been draggable but sortable? Would love some help this as I'm not the best with jQuery.

An example of my code is below or view my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PQFWq/).

index.html

#### Specify which items are included in your carousel (maximum 6 banners allowed):

```
    <p>Market Update and SJP Awards are default banners, these can be re-ordered but not removed.</p>
    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
        <div class="bannersdiv">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-state-disabled bannerslist">
                <div>Market Update (not able to be dragged out of this area)</div>
                <img src="images/img1.jpg" class="banners" />
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="bannersdiv">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-state-enabled bannerslist">
                <div>Investing for Income</div>
                <img src="images/img2.jpg" class="banners" />
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="bannersdiv">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-state-disabled bannerslist">
                <div>Awards (not able to be dragged out of this area)</div>
                <img src="images/img3.jpg" class="banners" />
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="bannersdiv">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-state-enabled bannerslist">
                <div>Long Term Care</div>
                <img src="images/img4.jpg" class="banners" />
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="bannersdiv">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-state-enabled bannerslist">
                <div>Later Life Planning</div>
                <img src="images/img5.jpg" class="banners" />
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="bannersdiv">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-state-enabled bannerslist">
                <div>Junior ISA</div>
                <img src="images/img6.jpg" class="banners" />
            </li>
        </div>
    </ul>

<h3 class="docs">Please select banners you would like to add to your carousel:</h3>

    <script>
        $(".sortable").sortable();
        $(".sortable").disableSelection();
        $('.sortable').sortable({
            cancel: '.sjppawards'
        });
    </script>
    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
        <div class="bannersdiv">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-state-enabled bannerslist">
                <div>E-Investor</div>
                <img src="images/img7.jpg" class="banners" />
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="bannersdiv">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-state-enabled bannerslist">
                <div>Work Place Pensions</div>
                <img src="images/img8.jpg" class="banners" />
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="bannersdiv">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-state-enabled bannerslist">
                <div>Market Update</div>
                <img src="images/img1.jpg" class="banners" />
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="bannersdiv">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-state-enabled bannerslist">
                <div>Investing for Income</div>
                <img src="images/img2.jpg" class="banners" />
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="bannersdiv">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-state-enabled bannerslist">
                <div>Awards</div>
                <img src="images/img3.jpg" class="banners" />
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="bannersdiv">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-state-enabled bannerslist">
                <div>Long Term Care</div>
                <img src="images/img4.jpg" class="banners" />
            </li>
        </div>
    </ul>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

js/js.js

```
$(function () {
 $("#sortable1").sortable({
     cancel: ".ui-state-disabled"
 });

 $("#sortable2").sortable({
     cancel: ".ui-state-disabled"
 });
 $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
     connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
 }).disableSelection();


 $("#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li").disableSelection();
 });

 $(function () {
 $("#sortable1").sortable({
     connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
     //receive: This event is triggered when a
     //connected sortable list has received an item from another list.
     receive: function (event, ui) {
         // so if > 10
         if ($(this).children().length > 6) {
             //ui.sender: will cancel the change.
             //Useful in the 'receive' callback.
             $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
             alert('Your selection has been cancelled. Maximum  6 banners are allowed in the carousel.');

         }
     }
 }).disableSelection();
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding a class `Nondrag` to the needed element's `<div class="bannersdiv">` and then do something like this

```
$( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
        receive: function (event, ui) {
             // so if > 10
             if (ui.item.hasClass("nondrag")) {
                 $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
                 alert("you can't remove these banners");

             }
         }
    }
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PQFWq/2/)